# Plotting local time to matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using MatPlotLib to plot some data, and I want to use the current time as the value of the x axis. I tried using datetime.now().time() but that wont work because it is using the HH:MM:SS.mmmmmm format. Is there any way to convert this so matplotlib understands aswell as it displays the time instead of converting it to seconds?

I want the time displayed on the plot to be HH:MM:SS

Comment: what is the time format you want? Can you please provide an example?

Comment: You can either use https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date.html and create your dates as a Matplotlib Date object *or* simply use `plt.plot` by plotting seconds or indices on the x axis, and then change the labels on x axis with `plt.xticks`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was much easier than I thought. All I did was this:

`self.pdata.xdata.append(datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=i))`

Now keep in mind this format will only work if you plot once each second, if you plot more often than once per second the time displayed will be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now().time()
stamp = now.strftime('%H:%M:%S') #stamp has what you want
```

Comment: Yes, I do get the correct format but I am unable to plot that since it has to be a float value to plot it in matplotlib